# What is the best way to track the webview browser of an app running in a webview in google analytics?

Tags: cordova, google-analytics

I'm using cordova, and I have GA view set as a mobile app. GA provides all kinds of data about the device (manufacturer, brand, OS etc.), but I'm also interested in the browser.

When I try to get information about the browser I see that all my traffic is classified as browser "GoogleAnalytics". From what I read ([here](https://www.e-nor.com/blog/web-analytics/browser-google-analytics) and [here](https://blog.dan-russell.com/2014/06/is-data-from-your-ios-and-android-apps-screwing-up-your-web-profile/)), this is GA's way of marking "mobile traffic".

**Is there a way to track both the device, and the browser in GA?**